# Strings of 2 characters or less causes Super Search timeout

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I'm having an issue very similar to Ryan Masuga as seen here: http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/3520/

I am running EE 2.7.3 and Super Search 2.1.3. In the original post I saw a mention to pagination, I wonder if that might be causing it? I'm using AB Pagination 1.6.3.

Here's my site: http://llumcmurrieta.org/

Basically a search for POB seams to spin forever and eventually timeout. Whereas a search for "POB" (with the quotes) works.

Here is my results block:

```
{exp:super_search:results
    site="internet"
    channel="pages|service_lines|bucket_services|bucket_treatments|bucket_conditions|news|pob_directory"
    exclude_entry_ids="618|935|871"
    highlight_keywords="strong"
    smart_excerpt="yes"
    paginate="bottom"
    limit="10"
    relevance_proximity="yes"
    search_words_within_words="no"
    fuzzy_weighting="yes"
    relevance="title=1+services_tags=5+ct_tags=5+page_keywords=5+services_introduction=2+ct_about=1+body=1+count_words_within_words"
    {!-- services_about and ct_sub_sections cause an error with super search -- see discussion: http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/17419/ --}
}
  {if count=="1"}<ul class="global-search search-results main-results">{/if}

  {embed="search/_result" id="{entry_id}" excerpt="{excerpt}" relevance="{relevance_count}"}

  {if count==total_results}</ul>{/if}
  {if super_search_no_results}
      <p>Sorry, we couldn't find anything to match what you are looking for.</p>
  {/if}
  {paginate}
  <style>.global-search.search-results.main-results {padding-top:61px !important;padding-bottom:60px !important;}</style>
  <div id="top-pagination" class="pagination-wrap pagination-top">
    <span class="count">
      Showing <strong>{abp_entry_from}</strong>-<strong>{abp_entry_to}</strong> results of {abp_total_entries} total
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-pagination" class="pagination-wrap pagination-bottom">
    <nav class="pagination">

      {if abp_has_previous}
      <span class="prev">
        <a rel="previous" href="{abp_previous_link}" class="page-previous" title="Go to page {abp_previous_page_num}">&laquo; Previous</a>
      </span>
      {/if}
      {if abp_current_page_num_liber > 3}
      <span class="page">
        <a href="{abp_first_link}">1</a>
      </span>
      <span class="page">...</span>
      {/if}

      {abp_pages padding="2" initial_size="5"}

      {if abp_is_current}
      <span class="page current">{abp_num}</span>
      {if:else}
      <span class="page">
        <a href="{abp_link}">{abp_num}</a>
      </span>
      {/if}

      {/abp_pages}

      {if abp_has_next}
      <span class="next">
        <a rel="next" href="{abp_next_link}" class="page-next">Next &raquo;</a>
      </span>
      {/if}
      {if abp_last_page_not_linked}
      <span class="page">...</span>
      <span class="page">
        <a href="{abp_last_link}">{abp_total_pages}</a>
      </span>
      {/if}
    </nav>
  </div>
  {/paginate}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using an embed inside {exp:super_search:results}? Sounds like this can slow down performance considerably. Also, have you tried turning off fuzzy searching, to see if that eliminates the timeout? This adds more processing, trying to find various combinations of fuzzy matches.